# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sticky'

Tags: jquery

**Update: Based on the useful advice below, I moved the 1.9.1. version to the top and took out 1.4. No more errors, but Sticky still doesn't work.**

I'm using the Sticky menu jquery plugin found here (http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky), which seems pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to get it to go without errors.

Here is my header:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen">
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/960.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
    <style>
        body {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
        #slides {display: none;margin-top:36px;}
        .slidesjs-container {width:1000px;height:252px;margin-bottom:-21px;}
        #slides .slidesjs-navigation {margin-top:-17px;visibility: hidden;}
        #slides .slidesjs-previous {margin-right: 5px;float: left;visibility: hidden;}
        #slides .slidesjs-next {margin-right: 5px;float: left;visibility: hidden;}
        .slidesjs-pagination {margin: 0px 6px 0;float: right;list-style: none;position:relative;z-index:1000;}
        .slidesjs-pagination li {float: left;margin: 0 1px;}
        .slidesjs-pagination li a {visibility:hidden;display: block;width: 14px;height: 0;padding-top: 14px;background-image: url(images/pagination.png);background-position: 0 0;float: left;overflow: hidden;}
        .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
        .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {background-position: 0 -14px}
        .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {background-position: 0 -28px}
        #slides a:link,
        #slides a:visited {color: #333}
        #slides a:hover,
        #slides a:active {color: #9e2020}
        .navbar {overflow: hidden}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cform.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
          $("#header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

I also have this in the body to run the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slides.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
    play: {
      active: true,
      effect: "slide",
      interval: 5000,
      auto: true,
      swap: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      restartDelay: 2500,
      width:936,
      height:247
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!  I'm a new stackoverflow-er and loving the knowledge here!

Comment: You're importing two different versions of jQuery. That's generally a recipe for pain.

Comment: You can't include two versions of jQuery without using `$.noConflict`

Comment: take out the 1.4 version. It's going to have all kinds of deprecated things.